# codename one graphs for the app dashboard and the tool bar

Tags: codenameone, toolbar

I have seen some of the graphs provided at codenameone.com but I would like to have such a UI

[image: screenshot example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this cn1lib which might be what you're after: https://github.com/chen-fishbein/CN1CircleProgress

You can also check out the `DoughnutChart` class which includes round charts of this type.

Comment: thank you Shai Almog, but can I find the CircleProgress, ArcProgress, CircleFilledProgress example classes to have a complete example for  https://github.com/chen-fishbein/CN1CircleProgress

Comment: The sample code in that page should work for you just the same for all these component types

Comment: how do I make the circle thickness  bigger

Comment: You mean stroke?
It seems to be hardcoded to 4: https://github.com/chen-fishbein/CN1CircleProgress/blob/master/CN1CircleProgress/src/com/codename1/progress/CircleProgress.java#L86
You can probably fix this for a fork of the cn1lib or submit a pull request that extracts this to a property that you can configure.

Comment: thanks, Shai.  I got that but I have failed to add in labels describing them

Comment: I don't follow that. Do you have a link for the changes you made on github?